# Bradley Hand ITCBold font is not displaying in mozilla and chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am facing a problem of brandley handwritten font , 
its look perfect in safari but there is a problem in both the giant browser so called mozilla and chrome .
Here's the code .

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: "BradleyHandITCBold";
    src: url(BradleyHandITCBold.ttf); 
    }
   .newfont
    { 
    font-family: 'BradleyHandITCBold';
    }
```

Comment: Do you test this local `file:///` or with a real webserver `http://` ?

Comment: its http://  <h2 class="newfont">Mooi Zeeland </h2> Please need your help mate @t.niese

Comment: One strange thing is, that FF and Chrome seem to interpret the file as plaintext. Did you already try `src: url(BradleyHandITCBold.ttf) format('truetype');` ?

Comment: Yes i have tried but its not working , its working fine in IE and Safari only the problem is mozilla and chrome

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:
There is only problem in mozilla and chrome because its modern browser and does not supports ttf font , so there is need to convert TTF to WOFF or WOFF2.
I converted it using TTF to WOFF Converter and its worked perfectly .
Here is the solved code .

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'BradleyHandITCBold';
        src: url("css/BradleyHandITCBold.ttf") format('truetype');
        src: url("css/BradleyHandITCBold.woff") format('woff');
        }
        .newfont
        { font-family: 'BradleyHandITCBold' !important;
        font-size : 31px;
        }
```

i am posting Here to help out other developer in future .
thanks for your comment @t.niese

Answer (score 0):

also really nice is it to have different font-weights for your fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "DIN";
    src: url("/media/fonts/din-regular-webfont.eot");
    src: local('?'), url("/media/fonts/din-regular-webfont.woff") format('woff'), url("/media/fonts/din-regular-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), url("/media/fonts/din-regular-webfont.svg#webfontfLFgafto") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "DIN";
    src: url("/media/fonts/din-bold-webfont.eot");
    src: local('?'), url("/media/fonts/din-bold-webfont.woff") format('woff'), url("/media/fonts/din-bold-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'), url("/media/fonts/din-bold-webfont.svg#webfontfLFgafto") format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
.bold-text {
    font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.regular-text {
   font-family: 'DIN', sans-serif;
}
```